# Hiding spots in a big city?

Tags: internal-consistency, modern-age

Basically, one of my protagonists is a science experiment on the run who ends up in a modern day big city (like LA or Chicago). She's teamed up with a hustler who's lived on the streets for most of his life. Thanks to a police/Illuminati-style organization putting a blockade around the city, the two are stuck there for the time being. What would be some decent places to hide out from the cops in a major city?

Answer (score 7):

**In Plain Sight**

I once got talking to some law enforcement friends of mine about catching criminals on the run and they made an interesting point - most of the people who are not with family or friends or their gang, etc. that they catch are either out in the bush or in small country towns when they are found. Their thinking is that less people means less police and therefore less chance of being caught. In reality though, smaller communities tend to be better able and more motivated to keep tabs on each other. So some new person entering their community is instantly suspect and subject to enquiry by the locals, civilian and law enforcement both.

On the other hand, large cities provide obscurity insofar as people *don't* spend a lot of time getting to know their neighbours and members of their broader community outside their friendship groups. The police have a lot more actual crime on their hands to deal with and are therefore less inclined to spend time looking into anyone who doesn't look suspicious to them.

So, your protagonist just needs to fit in. Get a small flat under an assumed name, get a job nearby, walk between the two, and don't go out looking for good times. Eat at home, shop locally, always pay your bills; people will leave you alone because there are more than enough people out there who will cause them grief to take up their time and attention.

You become a recluse, but in an environment that almost encourages it.

The worst thing you can do is try to find a nice abandoned warehouse or squat to live in, or try to hide under a bridge or the like. Ultimately, the police are motivated to clear these places out from time to time as the owners complain or as aberrant behaviour or drugs start to manifest in these micro-communities.

The only impediment to this kind of thinking is the increased surveillance systems that are going up in major cities around the world, allowing for people to be tracked to a much higher degree. But, it's important to note that the sheer volume of data from these systems is such that they are predominately used to look for specific vehicles or people in specific places at specific times to either validate or break alibis at the like. The TV and movie scenes of facial recognition systems scanning all the public faces in a city in real time isn't realistic. But, that is not to say that you would not eventually be found via such technology. In such a case, a simple latex facial disguise that makes your nose look bigger or cheekbones look higher or wider might be all you need to hide out in plain sight indefinitely if we are talking current levels of technology. Especially so if you spend some time early on finding the tracking cameras et al and finding ways to work and to the shops that avoid them.